# What is the default Kernel function and bandwidth used in KLaR package for naive Bayes classification

Tags: r

may I know what/How to search the Bandwidth and the Kernel function used in the KLaR pacake for naive Bayes classification? I used coding as below:

```
model = train(x,y,'nb',trControl=trainControl(method='cv',number=10))
```

the result shows:

```
usekernel  Accuracy   Kappa      Accuracy SD  Kappa SD  
  FALSE      0.7419321  0.4841762  0.04945793   0.09896329
   TRUE      0.8193841  0.6388997  0.03892331   0.07785660
```

From my understanding the final result is taken from the kernel estimation method on the data. May I know what is the type of Kernel function and bandwidth used in the naive Bayes classification in KLaR package? Thanks , and sorry for the Bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `klaR` help file it seems like unless otherwise specified a normal density is estimated

```
usekernel: If TRUE a kernel density estimate (density) is used for denstity estimation. 
           If FALSE a normal density is estimated.
```

Comment: Hi user51855, thanks for replying. I noticed that information, however, from the theory, Kernel distribution can be derived from several function like Gaussian, Epanechnikov, Quartic, Triweigh.. and there are also bandwidth selection techniques such as fix or plug-in...do you have some idea? thanks a lot

Comment: Hi user51855, sorry, thanks again...I get the answer now..it used the default of 'nrd0'..